# How to use ctypes to receive a wchar_t * string

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ctypes

Python-like code using ctypes

I am writing code in python to consume a dll. This dll requests a key that is generated in this format. How can I do this with python?

C++

```
string Code = "1234567890987654321";
            const wchar_t* key;
            wstring keystr = std::wstring(Code.begin(), Code.end());
            key = keystr.c_str();
```

I tried like that
Python

```
Code = "1234567890987654321"
keystr = c_wchar_p(Code)
key = c.create_unicode_buffer(keystr)
```

Comment: What about simply `c.create_unicode_buffer(Code)`?

Comment: Does not works. I have a dll that only accepts keys in this C ++ format. However I need to transform this with python. Thank you for your attention, colleague. Is there any way?

Comment: What do you you mean `does not work`? This is not specific enough to help with answering the question. One thing you could try checking is whether `wchar_t` is the same size in Python as in C++. If it is not the same size (it can be 2 or 4 bytes depending on compile/platform settings) you will have to probably make the string manually using an array of the appropriate integer type.

Comment: Please post **what you've tried so far, and where did you encounter problems** ("*does not work*" doesn't qualify as such). 
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start.

Comment: You need to show the prototype declaration of the function. If it needs a `wchar_t *` pointer to a constant string, then you can pass `Code` directly in Python 3. If it needs a pointer to a modifiable buffer, then use `create_unicode_buffer(Code)`.